# Simple python 'if' statement

Tags: if-statement

I'm trying to filter a large tab delimited file and print out just the lines with a score of >0.999 in one of the columns, but for some reason script's output continues to just print every line. Any insights as to why my "if score > 0.999:" isn't working as intended?

```
import sys
import string
import re


def split_lines(lines):
for line in lines:
    if line.find('#') >-1:

        print line
    else:
        #pass
        #fields = re.split('\t',line)
        fields = line.split('\t')
        score = fields[3]
        if score > 0.999:
            print score

        #else:
        #   pass



data = sys.stdin.read()
lines = data.split('\n')

split_lines(lines)
```

Comment: Does your script know that your incoming data is numerical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the string score to a number format, Decimal or float

```
if float(score) > 0.999
```